# Regex match all words from capturing group, not just 2

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
\b(\w+)\s+\1{1,}\b
```

Online test: https://regex101.com/r/iHnSCs/1m

but it only matches 2 consecutive words. How do I match more? I tried a couple of solutions but seems like I'm not getting it right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `\s+\1` in a non-capturing group, and repeat that group:

```
\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b
```

(either turn off the U flag, or make the repitition greedy with `?` - also note that `{1,}` simplifies to `+`)

https://regex101.com/r/iHnSCs/2

Comment: Right answer. Now reading about non-capturing groups. thanks.

Comment: Technically, you don't *have* to use a non-capturing group, it's just more appropriate than a capturing group - capturing groups are for when you want to *save* whatever's in the group for use later (like in a backreference), a non-capturing group allows for generic logical grouping without saving what exactly was matched there.